# What knot groups are Abelian?

Tags: general-topology, low-dimensional-topology, knot-theory

The knot group (the fundamental group of the complement of a knot) of the unknot is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the Hopf link is $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so those are knots (links) with Abelian knot group but are there any more?

Comment: At least for a knot, what would that say about the Wirtinger representation of the knot group?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a partial answer:

At least for knots, you're very limited in what can appear. The first homology group $H_1$ of a knot complement is $\mathbb{Z}$, which can be proved from Alexander Duality (see Hatcher, *Algebraic Topology*, section 3.3). Now the first homology group is always the abelianization of the fundamental group $\pi_1$, so if $\pi_1$ were abelian, it would have to be $\mathbb{Z}$.

This forces the knot to be the unknot, but I believe the reason for this is difficult. Here's a reference that quotes this result: http://web.utk.edu/~utkreu/docs/SGmini4.pdf

Comment: An easier way to see the $H_1$ of knot complement has one generator is to pick a generator in $\pi_1$, this is just a pointed loop. Then when one move the loop "upstairs" or "downstairs" in Wirtinger representation to another generator, two generators differ from a conjugation, but when you abelianize everything, two pointed loops represent the same loop in homology. Do this for all generators in fundamental group, then one sees $H_1$ of knot complement only has one generator.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of links, Corollary 1.6 of our paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.04839 proved a stronger result, which states that if $L$ is not the unknot or the Hopf link, then the fundamental group of its complement admits a non-abelian representation in $\mbox{SU}(2)$. The fact that the fundamental group is non-abelian was known earlier, and you may find a reference in Remark 1.7 of this paper.